# How to get the smallest positive integer solutions to $2\sqrt [3] {x} =3\sqrt [5] {y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the smallest positive integer solutions for $x$ and $y$ in the following equation? $$2\sqrt [3] {x} =3\sqrt [5] {y}$$

Comment: Well, have you tried raising both sides of the equation by $\text{lcm}(3,5)$?

Answer (score 2):

we have $$ 2\sqrt[3]{x} = 3\sqrt[5]{ y}$$ 
so cubing both side we have 
     $$2^3 x=3^3y^{\frac 35}$$

now 
      $$2^{ 3 \times 5}x^5=3^{ 3\times 5} y^3$$
so now we can write this 
      $$\frac{2^{ 3 \times 5}}{3^{ 3\times 5}}= \frac{y^3}{x^5}$$

so $$ y^3= (2^5)^3 $$
and  $$ x^5= (3^3)^5 $$

so$$ y=32$$ and $$x=27$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $$\sqrt[3]\frac{x}{27}=\sqrt[5]\frac{y}{32}$$

and $$x=27,y=32$$ is an obvious solution. No smaller powers of $2,3$ can work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

Suppose x an y are prime to each other, since 2 and 3 are also primes then we may write:

$2= (y)^{1/5}$ so $y=32$

$3=x^{1/3}$ so $x=27$

Answer (score 0):

Put each side to the power of $15$. Then

$$2^{15}x^5=3^{15}y^3.$$

From this, can you figure out the largest power of $2$ that needs to divide $y$? The largest power of $3$ that must divide $x$? Do you need any other primes?